# Permission denied in terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, permissions

I'm currently learning command line prompts and when I am trying to cp a file into a new directory I am getting the problem permission denied.

For example:

$ cp example.txt /temp

returns the line permission denied. Yesterday I noticed that every time I booted up terminal on my Mac it read new-host-#. I was able to change that to a new hostname, but in that process did I mess something up? Does that mean I changed to a host that doesn't have complete permissions. How do I change to the main user that has complete permissions or else how do I change my current hostname to have greater permissions access?

Thanks for any help. I've tried researching around, but I kind of don't want to mess around and muck things up further.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, don't try modifying anything under / instead, stick to your home directory.

Next, make sure you have a backup, it's easy to delete stuff by mistake if you're starting out on terminal.

A good idea now is to learn how to customize your terminal with safe (interactive) aliases to the file-destructive commands; see [My bashrc, bash aliases, profile and other files](http://stefaanlippens.net/my_bashrc_aliases_profile_and_other_stuff).

Next, read up on permissions.

Comment: uhh... it turns out I just placed a '/' in the wrong spot. Putting it before the temp makes it return permission denied. I don't know why. At least I know a lot about permissions now (and proper placement of my '/'s)

Comment: /temp usually doesn't exist on Mac and cannot be created unless you have superuser privileges.